# Add unique letters of a given String to a List

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I want to add a String's letters to a list, but I only want to add each letter once. For example, if the String is "HELLO AM CHRISTOS WHITE", some letters are appearing more than one time, so I want them to be added only one time.

I am thinking about two for loops:

```
for (int i=0; i< str.length(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j< str.length(); j++){
        if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j)) {
            myList.add(charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

But this code does not avoid duplicates.

Comment: Why two loops? iterate over a single originalLine.toCharArray(); if ( ! listContains(Char.valueOf(char[i])) addChar();

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a `Set` to achieve uniqueness of its content.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would be more efficient to use a `LinkedHashSet` for determining the unique characters. If you use a `LinkedHashSet`, the order of the unique characters of the input String will be preserved.

After a single loop, that would take linear time, you can add all the unique characters to your output `List`.

```
Set<Character> unique = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    unique.add(str.charAt(i));
}
myList.addAll(unique);
```

Answer (score 13):

To prevent duplicates in a collection, you don't need `List`, you need a `Set` (such as `HashSet`).

If you want to preserve the order you're adding your `String`s, use a `LinkedHashSet`.

Finally, if you want your `Set` to naturally sort your `String`s (or to be able to sort them with a `Comparator`), use a `TreeSet`.

**Example**

```
String foo = "ghghababcdef";
Set<String> hash = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> linked = new LinkedHashSet<>();
Set<String> tree = new TreeSet<>();
// iterating characters
for (char c: foo.toCharArray()) {
    // adding String representation of character to each set
    hash.add(Character.toString(c));
    linked.add(Character.toString(c));
    tree.add(Character.toString(c));
}
// printing...
System.out.println(hash);
System.out.println(linked);
System.out.println(tree);
```

**Output**

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h] // this may vary
[g, h, a, b, c, d, e, f] // keeps insertion order
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h] // sorted lexicographically by default
```

Answer (score 4):

as an alternative to the `Set` answer if you want to stick to the `List` solution.
You only need to loop once and make use of the `List.contains(Object)` method and check if the current `char` is already present in your `List`.

```
String str = "HELLO AM CHRISTOS WHITE";
List<Character> myList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i< str.length(); i++){
    if (!myList.contains(str.charAt(i))) {
        myList.add(str.charAt(i));
    }
}
for(char c : myList) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

output

> HELO AMCRISTW

Answer (score 0):

`j` is not assigned. I guess it is initialized to 0 so there is no exception

If you change second loop to `for(int j=0; j< str.length(); j++)` it will still not work, it won't print any letters that are duplicated in the string.

So think about what range j needs to iterate. You want to print any letter that has not already occurred in the string, if you get my jist.

Comment: It was just an example in my program is correct. The question was ansered anyway.

Comment: @ChristosMichael: In that case it would be a good idea, to accept the answer that best answers your question. It helps future visitors quickly identify a working solution to their problem. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: My answer was addressing the error in the code that you provided, how am I to know what you have in your program. Also, I assumed you wanted to address the problem in the implemented logic, did not realize you have other options to use well known data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no Character stream in Java 8 but here is a Java 8 way:

```
str.chars().distinct().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It might be less efficient but it is a readable one liner and it shows the power of streams.